# Is it prohibited to have multiple Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, moderation, duplicate-accounts

> Note that, in addition to the questions raised [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260430) I am asking if there is a regulation that prohibits this behaviour

It has come to my attention that some people are using multiple Stack Exchange accounts. I don't understand why they may want to do that, but it clearly opens the door to nefarious practices like voting for onesself

For instance, a guy that appears as [`marko`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337959), [`lux`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30356957), and [`rajal2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30387856) freely admits it in a comment *“Yes I'm not using that account now”* and in his question as `rajal2` *“I am sorry I am asking this question fro my other account”*

My questions are

- Is there a site rule that prohibits this practice?
- How should I deal with incidences of this practice, either via commenting, voting, or referral to moderators?

Comment: In general, having multiple accounts is OK. However, using multiple accounts to do things you *couldn't do with a single one* (e.g. vote fraud, ban circumvention) is not.

Comment: IIRC it's tot frowned upon to have multiple accounts per se, unless there are detected voting irregularities.

Comment: Per the accepted answer on the duplicate, *"Having multiple accounts is not explicitly disallowed."*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Why do you keep editing that back in? *It's answered in the duplicate*: **no**, it is not prohibited, unless you use multiple accounts to break other rules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't *keep* editing it back in. I rolled back my question because it isn't *asked* in the supposed duplicate. It is unreasonable to expect users to scan all of the answers in case they touch on something that isn't mentioned in the question

Comment: @BoltClock: That's very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Yes, having multiple accounts is usually OK. It's *not* Ok if multiple accounts are used to do bad things which you could otherwise not do, such as:

- Vote or answer acceptance fraud, accepting or upvoting something from your other account in order to gain rep.
- Circumventing restrictions, such as question bans or rate limits.

[As per this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260434/4428462):

> Having multiple accounts is not explicitly disallowed. It only gets to be a problem when those accounts have interactions between them to gain rep, or when extra accounts are made to circumvent bans or suspensions.

Comment: Normally, you would use multiple accounts to do things you couldn't accomplish with one, and that's OK too, as long as those things aren't an escalation of privilege.  For example, it's entirely appropriate to use a secondary account to experience limitations associated with having less than 50 reputation, such as edit suggestions, or the flag-for-close-reasons-UI, which certainly qualifies as "things you could not otherwise do"

Comment: @BenVoigt, Yes, that's true. I've edited my answer.