# Is it acceptable to have two accounts, one for asking and one for answering (no mutual voting)?

Tags: support, accounts

Is it accepted by Stack Overflow to have two accounts, one only for asking, one only for answering?

Of course, no mutual voting would be done. I have found nothing about that in the Help Center.

By the way, I have the feeling that many do that.

Comment: Related: [What should I do when I see a user with multiple accounts, and what action will be taken?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260430/1842065)

Answer (score 0):

> Is that accepted by stackoverflow?

We have no policies in place that prevent you from creating multiple accounts. But I strongly advice against it. An account should represent your contribution to SO , your knowledge, your strengths and your weaknesses (most of us have have a few bad posts in our accounts). Whatever response your post gets (look at this one for example :P), you should own it :)

> Of course, no mutual voting would be done.

Mutual voting will be considered as fraud. You will not be running the risk of your accounts getting blocked / deleted as long as you stick to your word.

> BTW, I have the feeling that many do that.

Now, I don't deny that many users have multiple accounts on this site. As long as they don't interact with each other, it's not considered as a wrong thing. We have some bots in here too. But that shouldn't matter (we deal with scores of sockpuppets everyday)

Edit :

> I don't want to risk that accounts are blocked

Your accounts will not be blocked if they stay out of each other's way.

Comment: Can you please show the link to the policies? There are people with 300k Points, but without a single question. Do they really never ask anything?

Comment: This seems to go against many other meta posts that say having multiple accounts is fine, so long as nothing abusive is going on.

Comment: @askolotl - Why do you care what other people do / don't do?.

Comment: I've seen various excus.. reasons for users to have multiple accounts.  I'm guessing that about 1 in a 1000 with multiple accounts has a legitimate reason for it.

Comment: @TheLostMind Basically I want to do it like that for myself. But I want to know if this is okay with the SO policies. I don't want to risk that accounts are blocked.  And I only mentioned other people, because I have the sure feeling that it is handled by many like that.

Comment: @MartinJames Some want go give a good impression. Therefore, they use the full name for answering, and an alias for asking.

Comment: @askolotl What I've seen happen is users having one main account and another account only for a bot. And yes, some users don't ask anything.

Comment: So is it okay with the SO policies or not? I have found no official information on this topic.

Comment: @TheLostMind, why not? I thought what was not ok was to have accounts interacting, which the OP said he's not doing... Can't we have a split personality disorder and ask as Z and answer as W? (edit) comment below answers it

Comment: @TZHX - That's right.. SO doesn't prevent people from having multiple accounts

Comment: @brasofilo - Well.. What if you want A to answer only Java, B to answer C#, ... X to answer JS and Y to answer MongoDB..  Now, its allowed, but I fear that such a trend is not good for the community. We already have hundreds of sock puppets that get created everyday. Some get caught, others don't.

Comment: I can't see how it's useful for the *same* person to have *different* accounts for the *same* stack exchange community.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I explained in this thread already.

Comment: @TheLostMind OK thanks, I've now also found the other answers. So as long as the accounts are not doing mutual interaction, like voting or answering each other, then it is okay. Can't upvote you, not enough reps ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind, I just felt this was asked on good faith and deserves a straight answer. And I understand why someone would want to do it without breaking any rule.

Comment: @brasofilo - I was merely pointing out how such things could be easily exploited. Yes, the answer is *it is OK* as long as you play fair :)

Comment: I would never suggest anyone to play unfair, and they'd really do it at their own peril... but I disagree with your opening statement "No, it's not OK to have 2 accounts one for questioning and another for answering"...

Comment: @brasofilo - edited my answer to seperate out my advice and what is allowed :)