# How do I flag a user for moderator's attention?

Tags: support, flags, new-users

I just found out that two users asked two questions that were close enough to get suspicious:

*https://stackoverflow.com/q/40075672/5897829*

*https://stackoverflow.com/q/40074564/5897829*

When you get on each asker's profile, it's the same picture account and they only asked one question.

I'm not saying that this user is violating sockpuppet rules (from here: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/319999)), but I'm wondering the following:

- Does the user know that his questions will be downvoted and therefore is creating the accounts to bypass the question limits?
- Or does he not know that he could have asked the two questions with the same account (I don't know the limits when it's your first question).

I have read question *[What should I do when I see a user with multiple accounts, and what action will be taken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will)*, but it doesn't say how I'm supposed to flag this user. I have visited the users' profile pages, but I didn't see anywhere to flag these users.

I guess the meta effect will deal with the appropriate action for this one, but for next time, how should I flag this user?

Do I flag the questions with a custom flag? Or is another option available?

Comment: As a side note: meta effect cannot take care of the users, no matter what. It will only deal with the posts