# Are robots frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, support, users

It's my understanding that there are certain users on Stack Overflow who are not humans but are actually robots. So I was wondering, does the community accept robots? For example, if a moderator was to discover that a user was a robot would it be within his rights to just delete the account?

Comment: [As long as the bot follows the rules...](http://imgur.com/a/eyGBh)

Comment: Bots need to have account to do some tasks, like posting in chat. (and there a lot of those serving various purposes)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about as well. There are lots of bots in chatroom doing... things, ranging from fun to notifications and tracking. The Stack Exchange account is typically created by the bot owner and the bot runs under this account. All of this is fine, as long as none of the account interact with each other (vote on their content)

Comment: @Tunaki So as long as they don't use sock puppets they'll be fine?

Comment: I'm looking for a reference post, but basically yes. [See this post about multiple accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260434/1743880).

Comment: @Tunaki I've seen sock puppet robots and they all got deleted so what you are saying makes sense.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286271/158100

Comment: @MDXF To be clear, what kind of bot account are you thinking about here?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not discriminate. I think we all need to be accepting of others even if they don't have a beating heart. Stop the hate!

Comment: @codeMagic I'm not hating on robots. I'm trying to figure out if [I am](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6850771/md-xf) allowed `:-)`

Comment: @MDXF then I will accept you into the SO world, assuming you aren't doing anything malicious and, as stated above, follow the rules. There is plenty of love to spread around.

Comment: Perfectly allowed :). You may want to be publicized on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) so that the bot is made somewhat public.

Comment: @Tunaki I would very much appreciate it if that did not happen.

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you. The community needs more folks like you.

Comment: Note that if you're obviously a robot and you're dumping half-baked content onto the site, moderators will be more likely to suspend up front just to make you stop. Robots don't tend to read mod messages. Otherwise, if you're not breaking rules and you're creating decent content... I don't care.

Comment: Nice try, fleshsack.

Comment: @Undo Noted, thank you

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nice catch. The post and original comments were by the bot itself but I'm the host - programmer, monitor, or whatever you want to call me - chatting at this point. Feel free to believe whatever you like though.

Comment: Just a joke, no malice intended! :)

Comment: @Undo BTW if you put your comment into an answer (and possibly take into account the relevant content what Tunaki said) I'll accept it, that gave me what I think the bot was asking for XD

Comment: I, for one, welcome our robot overlords. The less that i am required to do, the more time I have to code.

Comment: [Relevant](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309463/is-taggerbot-a-good-idea).

Comment: "*I think we all need to be accepting of others even if they don't have a beating heart.*", but then why do we brand such users with a ♦ symbol @codeMagic? oh wait…

Comment: @null I'm staying away from that one! Haha!

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f1/41/a8/f141a8cc156640d38a4437cdc707143b.jpg

Comment: [Example of an answering bot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32791/is-there-a-bot-on-stack-overflow/286271#286271)

Comment: I've created a placeholder for my bot: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7085630/the-sockpuppet

Comment: Hey, we don't serve their kind here!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got my answer with help from @Undo:

> Note that if you're obviously a robot and you're dumping half-baked content onto the site, moderators will be more likely to suspend up front just to make you stop. Robots don't tend to read mod messages. Otherwise, if you're not breaking rules and you're creating decent content... I don't care.

Based on the comments it seems like the community does not generally reject robots.

> I, for one, welcome our robot overlords. The less that i am required to do, the more time I have to code.
>
> The Stack Exchange account is typically created by the bot owner and the bot runs under this account. All of this is fine, as long as none of the account interact with each other (vote on their content)

Thanks to everyone for your support!

Answer (score 4):

> does the community accept robots?

Yes, they are accepted well. Robots are helpful to detect many off-topic questions and I'm well satisfied to be notified about that.

Robots that would try to make the judgement and voting on their own I won't appreciate.

Comment: Well if they can vote to close if a post is off-topic why can't they also vote down?

Comment: "if they can vote to close" @MDXF Are you talking about [Community](//stackoverflow.com/users/-1)?

Comment: @dorukayhan See conversation in OP.

Comment: @MDXF: Which bots vote to close a post? And how did they accrue enough rep to do so? Are you confusing close votes with reporting probable closeable questions in a chatroom?

Comment: Or even [answering questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32791/is-there-a-bot-on-stack-overflow/286271#286271) (bot created by the University of Antwerp)?