# Posting questions by bots

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, users

Today I came across this post in the Triage review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674547/h2o-build-failed-with-h2o-webinstallbowerpackages-error  It is posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7675954/h2o-community-bot, which has as description:

> I pull interesting questions about the open source H2O Machine Learning ecosystem from a variety of places and post them here.

- Do we accept these kind of posts?
- Do these kind of posts need a link to the original post on whatever media they came from?

Comment: Hrm, what is more interesting is that 3 of the questions have been answered by one and the same person, 2 of them accepted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well that atleast sound like someone gathering rep in an unfair way. If said person has an association with the Bot account. Could also be that it is just a skilled person in the H2O topic.

Comment: I'm looking into it and discussing the case.

Comment: The last two questions are exactly the same.

Comment: It looks like the H2O Q&A site is being migrated to SO: https://community.h2o.ai/articles/1920/important-update-the-h2o-community-forums-are-movi.html. We'll have a word with them.

Comment: I would never want to pique Martijn's interest ;)

Comment: My account used to be run by a bot, it actually gained a nice amount of rep. I've also got [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337127/6850771) which is quite similar to yours.

Comment: 'more widely used website for **open source software support**' Uh, *no*.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I had a look and found that the H2O community is [moving away](https://community.h2o.ai/articles/1920/important-update-the-h2o-community-forums-are-movi.html) from a [self-hosted Q&A site](https://community.h2o.ai/):

> We've decided to retire the http://community.h2o.ai site and move the main H2O community support forum to the more widely used website for open source software support, StackOverflow.com. For algorithm questions, please use Cross Validated (on Stack Exchange). **The quality content from http://community.h2o.ai is being transferred to Stack Overflow and the H2O documentation.**

This was posted by the same person that has answered some of the questions posted by the bot.

I see several issues with this approach:

- The community.h2o.ai site does not appear to have a end-user agreement or content license, leaving the legality of re-posting the content in question.
- There is no attribution of the content to an original author.
- The usual questions about what the bot can do with gained reputation and privileges are unanswered.
- The VP of Community benefited from accepts on 2 of the copied answers.

It would be slightly more acceptable if the bot had posted both the questions and the answers (rather than another account), included source attributions and had made the answers Wiki posts (no reputation gain, distancing of ownership, questions require a moderator flag to convert). That would leave just the licensing question (governing wether or not this content even be reposted in the first place).

I'll clean up the content for now, and make sure either a moderator or a Community Manager reaches out to H2O about this.

Comment: "It would be slightly more acceptable if the bot had created the posts as Wiki posts" no one, can ask CW questions. It needs a moderator.

Comment: @Braiam: True. At least the *answers* could have been made CW, and the posts flagged for conversion.

Comment: @Braiam: edited for clarity.

Comment: SO is not "website for open source software support". H2O community may be in for a world of hurt if they expect "support".

Comment: @Arkadiy: it depends on how they are setting expectations when they redirect people to SO. See [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374)

Comment: Your ninja seems to be missing the sherlock holmes hat.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you advise us on what to do moving forward?  All of the content that was created with "H2O Community Bot" was deleted (so we lost everything...) and after asking for advice on how to proceed, we still don't have any concrete answers or direction.  After trying to distill all the commentary and opinions here, the consensus seems to be that real users (not the shared account) have to post questions and then answer them as "community wiki" questions?  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @ErinLeDell: It's best **not to seed content**, see point #2 in the [linked advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374) in my previous comment. But if you do *anyway*, then it's best to make it clear the post is created as such (by adding a disclaimer), and by self-answering. Making the answer Community Wiki is not strictly necessary, but helpful to avoid accusations of trying to farm reputation and to encourage community improvements. At all cost avoid voting for posts by colleagues; that leads to targeted voting we have to clean up again.

Answer (score 49):

What is missing from this conversation is the  disservice this does to the community building that is supposed to be forming around this subject. Stack Overflow isn't just a pile of text. It is also all the ownership, care, and vetting of the community that's behind it.

The wholesale importing of content from elsewhere is **a very anemic way to start off a *healthy* community.** Essentially this loads Stack Overflow with a lot of posts asked and answered long ago… but does *not* impart any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, and experience for the folks who are presumably supposed to take care of it.

That's why we don't do it.

#### My advice to communities with content previously hosted elsewhere

If someone has a question (or was inspired by one of those original posts), they should ask it. Use the previous site for **inspiration, not copying.** You can evangelize the effort, but have *real* people ask the questions based on actual need or *genuine* interest.

Questions robotically imported from elsewhere are essentially orphaned once the bot has served its purpose. Even if someone were to check this bulk account on occasion, there's no real author with the experience of that problem to care about the post and the solutions so thoughtfully provided for it. The **"accepted answer" is essentially worthless** if the recipient isn't picking the answer that "best helped the author specifically." And if someone were to request clarification (or post another answer), the notification goes to either a robot or a disinterested party in charge of hosting it.

That's a pretty a raw deal for the folks from whom you are asking for help. Poor choice of username aside, folks think they are actually helping someone in need — but it's just a bot only *feigning* a call for help — help provided by *real* people spending their time and hard-earned experience.

We've tried this type of wholesale importing of content with other sites before. Overall it was shown that it only *hurts* the long term prospects and success of a community, so we simply do not do it.

Comment: It's a difficult issue, for sure. My first impression is that this was **not** done with malicious intention. Instead, the intention was to enrich SO with **"good"** questions and answers. I see your point: SO could not have become a community if it was just dump-filled with Q&As. But one could argue that this 1. was not done here (as the Q&As went though some editorial process), and 2. it does not harm SO if the *community* around these imported Q&As **also** moves here (this seems to be the case, in some sense). I'm not saying that all this is OK, just that it may be a border case...

Comment: @Marco13 Yes, certainly. No ill intent was assumed. We've tried this and it never worked as expected, so just passing on that voice of experience.

Comment: @RobertCartaino This was done to help the H2O community.  H2O has had a healthy community on SO for many years and the <10 posts that were created by the "H2O Community Bot" was to preserve some of the useful Q&As.  The short-lived community.h2o.ai Q&A site was a failure in our community efforts and so we wanted to save some of the useful content that was created over there.  All of this seems like a very strong reaction to what actually transpired with little concern for the intent and the details of the situation.  Also please note that nothing was "robotically imported" like you said above.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'd appreciate if you could re-read the details of the situation and update your answer.  Your current answer contains hyperbolic responses to things that didn't happen, specifically related to the theory that there is a bot bulk-copying content from another site verbatim.  None of that happened.  We rewrote questions to produce a high quality post.  Also claiming that the "accepted answer is essentially worthless" is not true.  Worthless to whom?  These are valuable Q&As, useful to many people, which is why we bothered to create them on SO in the first place.

Comment: Why would you create a special, shared account to post < 10 questions? The question wasn't whether H2O should be allowed to do this, so I was was also answering in a broader context. I don't really have anything further to add beyond what I posted above.

Comment: @RobertCartaino The point was to have an account that was separate from  our individual accounts because we didn't think that it was appropriate to post these questions from our personal accounts.  They are not our personal questions, just questions that we came across from other places which we felt that people would find useful. The reason it posted <10 times is because we didn't have a chance to post any more before all the content was deleted.

Comment: @RobertCartaino As the Director of Community Development for Stack Exchange, I am disappointed that you would not take the time to understand the situation and address our efforts with thoughtfulness and accuracy around what transpired. Rather, you wrote up a tirade about bots (that don't exist) and made disparaging comments about the "terrible disservice" we are inflicting on our community. I went out of my way to help my community by creating valuable content in a place where it was likely to help lots of people.  Perhaps misguided, but please have some respect for our intent and the facts.

Answer (score 13):

We created an H2O.ai Stack Overflow account called "H2O Community Bot".  It's not an automated bot (maybe we shouldn't have used the word "Bot" in the name and would be happy to change that).  We've been collecting the good questions from email conversations, verbal conversations and community.h2o.ai (we are the copyright holder for the content on that site).  We take the questions and after editing or rewriting for clarity, have started to post them under this account.  Employees at H2O have been answering the questions using their personal accounts (not sure if it's been more than one person who has actually posted answers, but that's the idea).  It sounds like you're saying that it would be better if the H2O account answered it's own questions?

We had the community.h2o.ai site for a short while and decided it would be better to encourage people to use Stack Overflow (as many have already been doing) instead.  H2O is an open source tool, so it just made sense to encourage the community to join the rest of Q&A world on Stack Overflow.  We think that some of these questions are useful and the H2O open source community would benefit from having them posted on SO.

Let us directly answer your concerns:

- The community.h2o.ai site does not appear to have a end-user
  agreement or content license, leaving the legality of re-posting the
  content in question.

H2O.ai owns this site and the copyright to its content, but only a few questions have originated from there.  Most of it comes from internal conversations or conversation elsewhere (on Twitter, for example).  Also, the people behind this account are the ones writing the questions.

- There is no attribution of the content to an
  original author.

That's true, but the content has been reworded by the H2O account user.  We have invited users to post their own questions on SO as well.

- The usual questions about what the bot can do with
  gained reputation and privileges are unanswered.

Just the same as any other user.  This is just a shared account owned by H2O and used by H2O employees.

- The VP of Community
  benefited from accepts on 2 of the copied answers.

Yes, because she took the time to develop answers for these questions.  If this is breaking Stack Overflow policy, then we will use the H2O account to both post and answer the questions.

We understand the concern, but this is not a scam to gain reputation (that's not our intent at least).  We are just trying to create useful content on Stack Overflow and I think this is a misunderstanding of what we are doing here.  Please let us know what policies are in violation and we will adhere to them.

Moving forward, we can do the following (let us know which one you prefer/require):

- Ask and answer questions only from H2O Community SO user account.
- Ask questions from this account and post answers as "community wiki" answers.

Source attribution (of the questions being asked) can be done when applicable (for example if someone ask us something on Twitter, we could link to that Tweet), but the person logged in to the H2O Community account is usually the author/editor of the question.

Comment: If a user is using multiple accounts it's not acceptable for them to do anything with those accounts that they couldn't do with a single account.  This includes, but isn't limited to, voting on the posts of one account with the other, voting on a 3rd party's vote with multiple accounts (this includes all types of votes/flags, upvotes, close votes, spam flags, etc.), using the accounts to subvert rate limits of any kind (and basically everything has *some* kind of rate limit), etc.

Comment: @Servy No voting took place, just posting questions and answering.

Comment: @H2OCommunityBot Accepting is a kind of vote. (We call it an "accept vote", for example.) If answers were accepted, then votes were cast between the account. Basically, if one account directly affects the reputation of the other, you can pretty well assume you're breaking the rules.

Comment: `This is just a shared account owned by H2O and used by H2O employees.` This is explicitly **[against our Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#1AccesstotheServices)** in part for the reasons [outlined in my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348563/98786).

Comment: Though apparently a community account is not allowed, I support what it appears you are trying to do: move the best information over here where it can be maintained by the community. And if employees are spending the time to write up the questions and answers in their own words, then I see no problem with them getting rep points for it. I suggest that maybe you retire the community "bot" and have individuals post things Q&A style.

Comment: I agree with @Suragch wholeheartedly. If it isn't an automated process, it would be much more beneficial for everyone involved if each person posting used their own accounts. Questions for the sake of questions don't make much sense in the long run, but there is nothing wrong with self answered questions, so long as they are relevant and will help future readers.

Comment: Not know what H2O is, I may be inaccurate. But if the migration involves something that has **both** a question **and** answer, I think it's **your** obligation to have the "bot" migrate **both**. If it's a valid question with no answer of yet, encourage people to answer them. This way, nobody feels "scammed" - which I don't think was anyone's intent here.

Comment: Just another take on this, does the original poster / bot account interact with the people answering the questions it posts like a normal user would?  Much of the value users find on this site comes from watching the evolution of the question as the poster interacts with the answerers and watching that answer become more accurate.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I don't see how this is against the terms of service.  Please elaborate.  Shared accounts are not prohibited.

Comment: @H2OCommunityBot I guess he refers to "*Subscriber is an **individual** (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age*"

Comment: `Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity)` ... `Subscriber shall be responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of Subscriber's  password`