# Should we allow bots that repost answers from other sources?

Tags: discussion, answers, robots

One of my more active tags is [blueprism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blueprism), a tag that caters to on-topic issues regarding the [robotic process automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation) (RPA) platform of the same name.

In recent months, it's apparent the company behind Blue Prism (also of the same name) has used [a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13877505/blue-prism-community) to repost the content of Stack Overflow questions, and post *answers* to the same questions, using roughly the following flow:

1. Stack Overflow user posts a question to the [blueprism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blueprism) tag.
2. Their robot scrapes this new question and posts it somewhere on their community site.
3. Stack Overflow users answer the question as normal.
4. Their robot re-posts any responses to the question received on the Blue Prism community site to the *answers* section of the original SO question.

(See also the [Stack App by the bot account](https://stackapps.com/questions/8706/stackoverflow-monitor-a-blue-prism-utility), a repost of [this earlier app](https://stackapps.com/questions/8441/stackoverflow-monitor-a-blue-prism-utility) which has links.)

While I believe the intent on Blue Prism's part is absolutely no less than well-meaning, I have a feeling this presents a multitude of the same problems outlined in a similar inquiry posted several years ago (["Posting questions by bots"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348522/posting-questions-by-bots)). In this specific instance, you'll notice that the posts coming back in from the Blue Prism community site *very* often do not adhere to Stack Overflow's quality guidance and are somewhat unhelpful in the context of Stack Overflow-esque Q&A, in almost direct opposition to the more forum-like atmosphere they've cultivated in their community.

Should we as community members do any more than just "downvote and move on" when we observe this behavior?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look good at all. Someone should reach out to them and tell them that SO isn't the sort of forum for that sort of thing, at least not without a human to clean up and vet potential posts. It *could* be useful, but it mostly isn't in their current approach.

Comment: It didn't work out well for [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047969/12695027), that seemed to have been cut short. The original Answer can be found [here](https://community.blueprism.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=145&MessageKey=c3b72d21-68c5-4637-b807-f896b2b7147a&CommunityKey=3743dbaa-6766-4a4d-b7ed-9a98b6b1dd01&tab=digestviewer)

Comment: While their intentions are good, I don't think that a forum where things like "I tried this but it didn't work" are acceptable answers should be mixed here. It works maybe 75 percent of the time.

Comment: @10Rep If you read it, it's a reply. They're sort of repeating the Question in bits and replying in bits. That's not uncommon.

Comment: @Scratte Yea, I know. I've been to other forums. I've [pinged them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053330/can-you-screenshot-an-open-webpage-in-a-blue-prism-process/65070578#comment115125058_65070578), but I don't know if it will work.

Comment: @10Rep Consider *not* abbreviating things like NAA. How are they supposed to know what that is? I do not think you picked a "Not an Answer" post either. I mean that's an answer phrased as a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Scratte I've pinged them in a chatroom, so there's no confusion.

Comment: @10Rep You don't think it's better to let a moderator or an employee handle this?

Comment: @Scratte If it gets resolved, then there's no need for an employee or mod to get involved, is there?

Comment: @10Rep Yes, there is! You have contacted a bot from a company and you are now representing Stack Overflow

Comment: "Should we as community members do any more than just "downvote and move on" when we observe this behavior?" - I think we should review the contributions like we would review any other contribution.  If the contributions are low quality should treat them exactly the same.  Eventually, the bot will be unable to submit answers, when that happens perhaps a human will intervene.,

Comment: Moot question IMO. No policy will dissuade the use of bots to scrape and repost content. Welcome to the internet.

Comment: Posting from SO to forum with attributions looks ok. But *"robot re-posts any responses"* is just wrong. Of course we will moderate any garbage put here, but this kind of additional strain shouldn't be allowed (imagine what 1000 bots can do). Maybe their poster there should mark reply as "answer worth to be posted on SO" somehow and only then bot will post it here? At least some sort of "humanity" and spam control.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034506/5211833) can be flagged as plagiarism I'd say, given that they copied content without specifying its source thoroughly (I don't consider "the Blue Prism Community" a good enough source ref).

Comment: It would be acceptable if the bot leaves an automated comment with a link to the forum thread after reposting it there.

Comment: @Bergi and what if the forum post reads "bump", or is otherwise not an answer to the question at all?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't care about the content of the thread. Just an "*This question was reposted to the Blueprism Community Forum at http://…*" comment so that *if* there is valuable content it can be found easily and it is clear what happened. The only thing worse than cross-posting is cross-posting without mentioning it :-)

Comment: @Bergi I thought you were advocating the bot to still post forum posts here, but with a comment to the post.

Comment: It seems to me that Blue Prism is essentially using Stack Overflow as a way to drive traffic to their forums. Regardless of the other reasons listed why this bot is a bad idea, piggy-backing off SO's popularity seems unethical.

Comment: Wouldn't the bot run into a ban if we downvote it for posting poor content?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes; at which point they might create a new account for it.

Comment: @TylerH at which point the mods will probably consider this ban evasion.

Comment: @IanKemp the idea doesn't seem unethical. The company doesn't really say "you should go to our forums to see the answers". It's a two-way communication, so answers on the forum are reposted here. Seems quite fair as an overview. The implementation is lacking, as SO was fundamentally not meant to be a forum, so posting forum replies here runs a high risk of them being under the quality standards. *That* I would consider it a bit rude but I don't think it's actually malicious.

Comment: @VLAZ Well sure, but my point is you're just trading one unacceptable behavior for another. Better to outright say this is against policy.

Comment: Just would like to add to the conversation around intent - I don't at all think there are any bad intentions afoot. I'll disclaim that my employer and the Blue Prism company have a very tight-knit relationship - from what I know about them I have no reason to assume that they are attempting to do anything but try to help users that have reached out on Stack Overflow, where the Blue Prism-related traffic is low, using content from their (higher-traffic) community. As it's been stated, however, the issue is primarily that the content being re-posted here doesn't meet the site's standards.

Comment: Agreed with your comment and edit. We don't think that there's any evidence of bad faith on anyone's part. We just don't think that the strategy is an acceptable one. We'll try to work towards a strategy that works better for both sides, as we do appreciate and encourage the participation of paid support staff (just as we do with *any* experts) in answering questions. Related reading: [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community)

Comment: This provides an interesting glimpse into the future, IMO.  The efforts by many here may be obsolete in our lifetime and seen as akin to cutting grass by hand.

Comment: @java-addict301 Not even close. The bot was copying answers from *actual humans* from one site to another. Not generating the answers itself.

Comment: My naive take is humans aren't allowed to plagiarize content from other sites, so bots shouldn't be allowed to, either.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. It is a violation of our policies on *multiple* levels.

I don't want to go into too many details here, but moderators and staff have discussed this particular case internally, decided that it is a clear misuse of our platform that is fraught with various issues, and have moved forward with handling it by removing all of the bot's answers and reaching out to the humans behind it.

As far as what community members should do, raising a moderator flag is appropriate for this, as with anything else that you see that makes you uncomfortable. A single custom flag on one of the answers, with a detailed explanation that tells us what your concerns are, is sufficient. You don't need to flag each and every one of the answers, since the problem is common with all of them.

Answer (score 31):

I'm not a fan of bots copy-pasting answers from off-site resources (or internally, for that matter) to Stack Overflow. There are several problems with this:

- The format might not be compatible. The Blue Prism forum, for one, seems to be a lot more "chatty" than Stack Overflow, with "Hi", "thanks" and salutations very prevalent. Other potential issues are e.g. markdown support and HTML rendering.
- Responses that are not an answer might be copied.
- There might be license violations. In the case of Blue Prism copying from their own forum that should not be a problem, but non-company bots copying content might inadvertently violate licenses. The bot you mentioned had all their posts deleted by a moderator for plagiarism, since they didn't properly attribute the source on any of their answers.
- Bot accounts won't follow up on comments.

... and several others, such as a bot receiving reputation for work of others.

If you come across one of these bots, investigate several of their posts, make detailed note of the pattern and use a custom flag to explain the issue. In case of clear copy-paste (even with attribution) it's usually considered plagiarism, especially if the post only contains copied content, rather than having copied content as a reference. Use a custom flag, saying it's plagiarised and link to the source.

---

Bots that copy posts from Stack Overflow to elsewhere are probably not something Stack Overflow, the company, can do anything about in an easy way. It'd again come down to licensing issues, which would require legal action to solve. In any case not something us Stack Overflow users can help with.

Comment: "In the case of Blue Prism copying from their own forum that should not be a problem..." It actually might be a problem. It depends under which license the content of their own forum is existing and if the bot can be seen as an author. I could even imagine that the terms of service of StackOverflow implicitly assume a human as user, so bots posting content here, is not a legal possibility. Whoever created the account would be responsible for the posted content.

Comment: The bot probably isn't at least 13 years old, either.

Comment: @Trilarion "*Whoever created the account would be responsible for the posted content.*", yes, this. But it doesn't matter if the actions happened through a bot or not. StackOverflow certainly allows accounts managed by bots, not just the Community♦ one but also anyone registering their application for an API key, which Blue Prism did.

Comment: @Trilarion If Blue Prism copies content from their own forum, then the license issue is between themselves (or whoever operates the bot) and their forum users. Practically we're not involved.

Comment: @iBug If somebody (human or bot) tries to sneak non CC-licenseable material in here, it would impede our operations and cause some havoc. Now what is the chance that some random material from the Internet plays well with the content license here?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The programmers of that bot are probably over 13 years old, and perhaps the bot can be seen as the programmers interfacing with the website. Much like how running malicious software that causes damage to a person can open you up to lawsuits, as you are culpable, the bot programmers are culpable for  the badly behaving bot.

Comment: @JohnGlen r/woooosh ;)

Answer (score 2):

All posts should be judged solely on the intrinsic quality of the post's contribution, not on ***any*** a priori properties of the poster.

Whether Blue Prism's bot is making quality contributions is a fair question, but I urge Stack Overflow to focus its quality assessment on the *contribution*, not irrelevant properties of *contributor*.  Let SO's robust scoring system handle the quality assessment and contributor credit assignment without prejudice.

Comment: That's true. If the bot keeps writing bad answers, then eventually it will get banned.

Comment: @10Rep That doesn't really clarify anything. What if the bot writes great Answers? There's a lot of legal stuff that needs sorting out to just handle it with community curation.

Comment: @Scratte if the company writes a bot to give their answers to us, then "legal stuff" isn't really a big issue.

Comment: @10Rep How is that? Can you just site the license of the original site or do you also need to give attribution to the bot when you include their proposed code into your project? What happens if the Answer is edited? Are bots even covered in license agreements? Can you just give attribution to the bot? Who's responsible for the posts that the bot posts here? It cannot be a group of people as the Terms of Services doesn't let a company have an account that users share. What if the user quits? Honestly, I'm sure that there are lots of lots of legal stuff that I haven't even thought of yet..

Comment: I do agree with this line of thinking wholeheartedly (allow the scoring system to do its job), albeit not without some concern, with the example in the OP being a perfect illustration. I'm not familiar with the internals of how downvote-triggered suspensions and bans work, but I think lots of answers and comments in this thread are glossing over an important fact that [tag:blueprism], and lots of other tags like it, simply don't regularly attract the volume of users with downvoting privileges to have any material effect in this regard. (1/2)

Comment: Sure, we can run to Meta every time we see something like this (which, granted, isn't particularly often at all), but is "let the scoring system do it's thing" something we can rely on 100% for smaller/niche tags? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? (2/2)

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, that is a fair point. But I'm sure the Blue Prism company is fine with it, and they wouldn't suffer. But the user who created the account may get in some trouble.... But it doesn't take long to get answer banned, that's for sure.

Comment: I wonder if bots that get enough rep (by writing at least mediocre answers (maybe FGITW heroes)) should then also be allowed to vote and take part in the quality assessment. Or would it be reserved for human users?

Comment: Although I agree with the *spirit* of this answer, there are practical issues with the source, as well. Copying posts from a forum into an entirely different environment, with radically different rules and norms, is not going to end well. It would be irresponsible for moderators not to take issues like that into account.

Comment: @CodyGray: Gotcha.  I'll save the intrinsic quality argument for a more worthy bot.

Comment: What about something akin to a ddos attack? Say 1,000,000,000 new bots are created and start posting lots of garbage after getting enough rep.

Comment: We have plenty of system-level checks in place that would prevent that, @JohnGlen.