# Someone signed up with my email, there's no "not me" link

Tags: feature-request, email

I face this problem on many different sites. People register on various services with my email address. Often, those welcome emails provide no way to stop getting email without a lengthy process of resetting that password and manually deleting the account. I don't know why people do this, and I know that these "welcome to x site" emails are just spam to begin with.

As I'm a user of SO under a different email account, I don't want to just mark email from SO as spam, but I definitely don't need multiple welcome emails, asking me to confirm my password and then another "reminder" to complete registration.

Let me click one link to blacklist this email address from further communication.

Comment: I sympathize with this plight. Several years ago, someone else whose name is the same as mine apparently decided that *he* owned my Gmail email address, and started using it to sign up for all sorts of things. I still regularly get emails intended for him. I don't know how he hasn't figured it out by now, since none of the accounts he tries to create ever get successfully created, but he's a persistent fellow, so he keeps trying. It's taught me a lot about the uselessness of "unsubscribe" and "not my account" links.

Comment: You have a "commonname@commonemailprovider.com" address?

Comment: Hello, *other Will.*  Until you get a name change the email harassment will continue! *dun dun duuuuun!*

Comment: OMG that was hillarious @Will.

Comment: @Will you're the worst human being I've ever come across. *Now which one of you two do I mean? The existential uncertainty will drive you both crazy!*

Comment: What *will* be done about this?

Comment: The [Contact Us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) link is likely to be your best bet here.

Comment: As a temporary measure, you could reset the password, turn off all email notifications, and don't delete it. Freeing up the account will allow it to be created again.

Comment: @SamuelLiew but having multiple accounts is against T&C...

Comment: @Troyseph no, it's not. However, using them for voting fraud is. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260434/584192

Comment: Why won't Will will Will his email address? Then we can be done with this :).

Comment: @Kit don't give anyone any ideas now.

Comment: Makes one wonder how many times typing @Will or similar has notified the wrong person.

Comment: You really need to change your email from test@test.com.... :)

Comment: I'm on pins and needles. Will Will will Will "Will?"

Comment: @MrLister It's a bit spooky to randomly read this comment thread and have it end with a comment by someone using my name...

Comment: So, who is posting here? You? or the usurper?

Comment: @BSMP are you sure the  *second* "buffalo" should be capitalized?  I can't make a sentence that starts "<bully> <New York>..." or "<bison> <New York>"...

Comment: @CodyGray I have the same situation but I also receive emails from his family and colleagues. I asked them to stop several times but it seems that their email clients have "memorized" my email address. At this point I know a lot about this person. I have even received a job offer in his stead.

Comment: @CodeGray: Same here. I receive someone else's personal messages of confirmation for business trips, new deals, all sorts. And I've managed to confirm that they're not spam. It's baffling!

Comment: I used to get bank statements for some chap in the US who has the same name as me... I get emails for at least four other people who have the same surname and initial as me as well. Telling them that they're emailing the wrong person doesn't work either, they just keep on doing it...

Comment: @BSMP Correction: "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."

Comment: Guessing your email is *will@gmail.com*... If it is then tht's quite a common email. No wonder that user is spamming you

Comment: Gee, now I feel like I owe an apology to bob@bob.com

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1279/

Comment: One of my email addresses is a totally random pattern at hotmail.com, but I still get emails for someone else. They managed to have the same address as me, only at hotmail.co.nz.

Comment: I too am the owner of such an e-mail address. Every year I recieve New Year's wishes from people I don't know for people who are not me. Someone once tried to sell a bike on some plattform (I didn't click the activation link for the auction) and I recieved an invitation for a house viewing in a town about 200km from where I live (rent was cheap, but commute would've been too long) and two different people signed up for mobile phone contracts. Also, some people sign up for various NSFW sites using MY e-mail. It makes me wonder: How hard is it to type in your own, correct e-mail-address? :(