# Is it okay to create two user profiles, one to answer the other's questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, users

This is rather a strange situation. I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69758081/16775594), in which a question was asked by one user, and answered 9 minutes later by another user whom the evidence suggests is another profile run by the same user.

First, the evidence (you can also read my comment on the answer):

1. The question was answered only nine minutes after being asked, and the answer seemed to have nothing to do with the question. The question was about "how to find the WiFi trigger directory", and the answer showed commands that clone some Arduino git repo.
2. The users have the same username, and the person in the profile pictures looks to be the same as well, although I could be mistaken with the masks.
3. Both the question and the answer were extremely short and vague, lacking any explanation, yet both users seem to have intimate understanding of the problem.
4. Both users joined on the same day, and both only have posts on that one question.

I will provide both the question and the answer here.

Question:

> #### how to find trigger directory on arduino
>
> I have a problem uploading the Arduino code and there is an error message in the WiFi Trigger directory. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6tk.png)

Answer:

> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino.git
> $ cd Arduino/build
> $ ant dist
> enter code here
> ```

So my question: is it considered acceptable to create separate user profiles, one just to answer the other's questions? Would this be considered "gaming" the site, or could it just be attributed to lack of knowledge of the site's workings?

Comment: If they are pretending to be different users, then that is illegal.

Comment: No, it's not ok. Why would you want to do that anyway ?

Comment: @TGrif Hypothetically, if both users got enough reputation, they could upvote one another's posts, which would be serialized voting. But here, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Someone isn't allowed to vote for themselves or give themselves reputation in any way, So they're not allowed to accept their Answer. They can't upvote due to the reputation requirement. You should probably raise a custom flag on this instead of posting on meta. There's nothing meta can do about it.

Comment: Think about serial bountying: Repeatedly awarding bounties to one another. That's bad, but considering none of them have 75 rep, that's unlikely. If you come upon one of these, flag any one of their posts and have a mod take a look.

Comment: @Scratte Does SO prevent users with the same email address from accepting each other's answers? Because I don't see any other way that the site software would know that the users are run by the same person.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will?rq=1

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I don't think you can have two accounts with the same email. I'm pretty sure that would result in them automatically getting merged.

Comment: They created an other account to repost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69762617/5468463

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is forbidden! You are allowed to have more than one account but these accounts can't interact with each other. Asking and answering the same question is an abuse of multiple accounts. When found, the secondary accounts will be deleted and the main account might be suspended.

When you notice a similar situation in the future, please raise a moderator flag and explain the issue with links to both profiles.

Comment: Strictly speaking it _is_ allowed, asking and answering the same question isn't abuse as it can be done with a single account. It becomes abuse as soon as either account votes on the other (including accepting the answer).

Answer (score 4):

In general, *no*.  You're not allowed to let the accounts you create interact with one another in such a way that lets one boost the other (think rep boosting, bounty boosting, etc).

I would explicitly recommend that you flag this with a custom mod flag.  They can see metadata that mere mortals can't and take action based on that.  While I smell smoke also, I can't confirm that this is a fire because I lack the visibility into the circumstances of this account's creation.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you have evidence of fraud (and not a mistake made out of ignorance), then by all means you should flag for a moderator. Otherwise, leave a comment explaining [how duplicate accounts can be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), and take any relevant moderation actions, such as moving information that should have been an edit into the post and flagging it for deletion.

Coming from a perspective other than Stack Overflow, it's extremely common to see people creating new, obviously duplicate accounts to post answers (sometimes really a comment or edit in the answer box) to their own questions. Do they gain any benefit from this? Not really. In fact, it's usually harmful to them overall as they don't receive any of the benefits from having a single account, such as upvotes on their question or the ability to comment with low rep anywhere on the question or its other answers. But they don't know that; the site might as well be any other forum.

The only real benefit they get is that it's easy to create another account, easier than remembering how you got into the other one. They sometimes don't realize it's not the same account.

Only the user themselves can fix having two accounts, by going through the merge process. Moderators can't do anything special to help. They have no power anymore to merge accounts. And I believe that suspending either account would prevent the user from having any access if they did manage to merge their accounts.

Merges don't punish the user. It's just as if they never created a second account in the first place. This is proof that it's really not a terrible violation of the rules to make a mistake like this.